# How to get month according to day of year

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, calendar

I have input like `34` which means its `3rd day of February`, but how to determine programatically in Java by taking `day of year` and getting `month name` or month `month value like 0 for January` is there any API in Java that handles this. I searched in `Calendar class` but did not found any.

Comment: You can implement it by yourself.

Comment: Just start with January 1st and add `dayOfYear - 1` days...

Comment: You will also need to know if you are in a leap year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 34);
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

Will return 1 (as Months start with 0).

Comment: Does this account for leap years as well ?

Comment: If you set the year accordingly, yes. GetInstance() will give you the current date including year.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2014, 0, 1);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 34);
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-inventing wheel :-(

```
package com.test;

public class FindMonthByTotalNumberOfDays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input = 89;
        int monthDigit = extractMonthDigit(input);
        System.out.println("Total number of days " + input + " lies in month " + monthDigit + ".");
    }

    private static int extractMonthDigit (int totalNumberOfDays) {
        int result = -1;
        if(isInBetween(1, 31, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 0;
        else if(isInBetween(32, 59, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 1;
        else if(isInBetween(60, 90, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 2;
        else if(isInBetween(91, 120, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 3;
        else if(isInBetween(121, 151, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 4;
        else if(isInBetween(152, 181, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 5;
        else if(isInBetween(182, 212, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 6;
        else if(isInBetween(213, 243, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 7;
        else if(isInBetween(244, 274, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 8;
        else if(isInBetween(275, 304, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 9;
        else if(isInBetween(305, 335, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 10;
        else if(isInBetween(336, 366, totalNumberOfDays)) result = 11;
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean isInBetween(int min, int max, int days) {
        boolean isInBetween = false;
        if(days >= min && days <= max) {
            isInBetween = true;
        }
        return isInBetween;
    }
}
```

Comment: will not be valid for leap year. :)

Comment: Tried to write a code quickly, agree no leap year is considered, also I am only printing number which needs to be mapped to actual Month etc... Thanks Vishrant.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar    calendar    = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfYear_ );

Date                resultDate      = calendar.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat    stringFormat    = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MMM" );
String              result          = stringFormat.format( resultDate );
```